# absolute continuity and density of a probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am learning probability theory right now but measure theory again gets me stuck (I have done some real analysis).

> Let $E=(0, 1)$, $B$ are the Borel subsets of $E$, $P(A)$ is the length of $A$, $A\in B$. Define the random variable $X(e)=min\{e,\frac{1}{2}\}$. $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\nu$ is counting measure on $\chi_0=\{\frac{1}{2}\}$, $\mu=\lambda+\nu$. Prove the distribution $P_X$ of $X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$ and find the density of $P_X$.

I first begin with considering whether $\frac{1}{2}\in B$ or not and for the absolute continuity. $\mu(B)=0$ suggests that $\frac{1}{2}\notin B$ thus $\lambda(B)=\nu(B)=0$. Then $P_X(B)=P(B\cap(0,\frac{1}{2}))=\lambda(B\cap(0,\frac{1}{2}))=0$.

My question is (1) am I doing right for absolute continuity? and (2) how to find the density? I know Radon-Nikodym Theorem but I don't fully grasp it.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to say that $A\in B$ when $B$ is a Borel set. Maybe you mean that $B$ is the Borel $\sigma $-algebra on $E$?

Comment: @Masacroso the question is almost the same on Theoretical Statistics by Robert W. Keener, p20. let $B$ be the Borel subsets of $E$. this term is unusual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Further note that: $$P_{X}\left(B\right)=\frac{1}{2}P\left(X\in B\mid X<\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}P\left(X\in B\mid X\geq\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}Q\left(B\right)+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(B\right)$$
where $Q$ and $\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}$ are both probability measure
on $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right)$.

So in short we have: $$P_{X}=\frac{1}{2}Q+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Here $Q<<\lambda$ and $\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}<<\nu$.

If $f$ is a density for $Q$ wrt $\lambda$ and $g$ is a density
for $\delta_{\frac{1}{2}}$ wrt $\nu$ then $\frac{1}{2}f+\frac{1}{2}g$
is one for $P_{X}$ wrt $\mu=\lambda+\nu$ provided that $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$
and $g\left(x\right)=0$ whenever $x\neq\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: can we have more details about $f$ and $g$? $P_X=\lambda(B\cap (0,\frac{1}{2}))+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{I}_{B\cap \frac{1}{2}}$ I'm thinking of some indicator functions

Comment: $Q$ can be recognized as uniform distribution on $\left(0,\frac12\right)$. It has density $f(x)=2\times1_{\left(0,\frac12\right)}(x)$ wrt $\lambda$. Further $g(x)=1_{\{\frac12\}}(x)$ serves as density of $\delta_{\frac12}$ wrt $\nu$.